# what is the meaning of these logs which are the results of kws_test.py in pocketsphinx?

Tags: python, pocketsphinx, keyword-search

I am using **pocketsphinx** for keyword search. I ran the kws_test.py in the pocketsphinx_master folder.Script run and  displayed the following logs. Can anyone understand what the logs are saying as i am new to pocketsphinx?

```
import sys, os, pyaudio
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *


modeldir = "../../../model"
datadir = "../../../test/data"

# Create a decoder with certain model
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', os.path.join(modeldir, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-dict', os.path.join(modeldir, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))
config.set_string('-keyphrase', 'forward')
config.set_float('-kws_threshold', 1e+20)


# Open file to read the data
#stream = open(os.path.join(datadir, "goforward.raw"), "rb")

# Alternatively you can read from microphone


p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
stream.start_stream()

# Process audio chunk by chunk. On keyphrase detected perform action and restart search
decoder = Decoder(config)
decoder.start_utt()

while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
         decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
    else:
         break
    if decoder.hyp() != None:
        print ([(seg.word, seg.prob, seg.start_frame, seg.end_frame) for seg in decoder.seg()])
        print ("Detected keyphrase, restarting search")
        decoder.end_utt()
        decoder.start_utt()
```

### Results

> INFO: kws_search.c(406): KWS(beam: -1080, plp: -23, default threshold 449, delay 10)
>
> INFO: cmn_live.c(88): Update from < 41.00 -5.29 -0.12  5.09  2.48 -4.07 -1.37 -1.78 -5.08 -2.05 -6.45 -1.42  1.17 >
>
> INFO: cmn_live.c(105): Update to   <  1.29 -3.54 -2.37 -2.43 -0.78 -1.90 -5.97 -3.73  2.61 -1.19 -3.92  1.59  2.12 >
>
> INFO: cmn_live.c(88): Update from <  1.29 -3.54 -2.37 -2.43 -0.78 -1.90 -5.97 -3.73  2.61 -1.19 -3.92  1.59  2.12 >
>
> INFO: cmn_live.c(105): Update to   <  1.14 -3.08 -1.59 -1.89 -1.13 -1.60 -3.96 -3.55  0.80 -1.84 -3.86  0.40  0.41 >
>
> INFO: cmn_live.c(88): Update from <  1.14 -3.08 -1.59 -1.89 -1.13 -1.60 -3.96 -3.55  0.80 -1.84 -3.86  0.40  0.41 >
>
> INFO: cmn_live.c(105): Update to   <  0.95 -2.63 -0.96 -2.08 -1.09 -2.06 -3.46 -3.84 -1.00 -2.19 -3.07 -0.32 -0.23 >

Comment: I do not think that it is related to any error or problem ?

Comment: yes. there is no error. have you any idea about the results i got. I am a beginner here. @ShubhamSharma

Comment: It does not give expected output (i.e 'forward') . what may be the issue here.

Comment: Check the mic first is it really working ? and does it support rate 16000 ?

Comment: Itz issue of the mic. thanks