# PocketSphinx is not listening

Tags: java, android, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I would like to implement the library PocketSphinx in my Android project but I fail with it since nothing happens. It doesn't work and I don't get any errors.

This is how I tried it:

1. Added [pocketsphinx-android-5prealpha-release.aar](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo/blob/8f5ccb88eb24eb5155f52a7366911e5c615e254e/aars/pocketsphinx-android-5prealpha-release.aar) to `/app/libs`
2. Added [assets.xml](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo/blob/8f5ccb88eb24eb5155f52a7366911e5c615e254e/models/assets.xml) to `/app`
3. Aded the following to `/app/build.gradle`:

```
ant.importBuild 'assets.xml'
preBuild.dependsOn(list, checksum)
clean.dependsOn(clean_assets)
```

4. Added [sync](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo/tree/8f5ccb88eb24eb5155f52a7366911e5c615e254e/models/src/main/assets/sync) (with all sub-files) into `/app/assets`
5. Cloned the following repos into my root-directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase
git clone https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx
git clone https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android
```

6. Executed `gradle build`

This is how my code looks like:

```java
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.HashMap;

import ch.yourclick.kitt.R;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Assets;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Hypothesis;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.RecognitionListener;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizer;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizerSetup;

public class SttService extends Service implements RecognitionListener {
    private static final String TAG = "SstService";

    /* Named searches allow to quickly reconfigure the decoder */
    private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";
    private static final String FORECAST_SEARCH = "forecast";
    private static final String DIGITS_SEARCH = "digits";
    private static final String PHONE_SEARCH = "phones";
    private static final String MENU_SEARCH = "menu";

    /* Keyword we are looking for to activate menu */
    private static final String KEYPHRASE = "oh mighty computer";

    /* Used to handle permission request */
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO = 1;

    private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> captions;

    public SttService() {
        // Prepare the data for UI
        captions = new HashMap<>();
        captions.put(KWS_SEARCH, R.string.kws_caption);
        captions.put(MENU_SEARCH, R.string.menu_caption);
        captions.put(DIGITS_SEARCH, R.string.digits_caption);
        captions.put(PHONE_SEARCH, R.string.phone_caption);
        captions.put(FORECAST_SEARCH, R.string.forecast_caption);
        Log.e(TAG, "SttService: Preparing the recognition");

        // Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
        // so we execute it in async task
        new SetupTask(this).execute();
    }

    private static class SetupTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception> {
        WeakReference<SttService> activityReference;
        SetupTask(SttService activity) {
            this.activityReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }
        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Assets assets = new Assets(activityReference.get());
                File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
                activityReference.get().setupRecognizer(assetDir);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return e;
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
            if (result != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onPostExecute: Failed to init recognizer " + result);
            } else {
                activityReference.get().switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (recognizer != null) {
            recognizer.cancel();
            recognizer.shutdown();
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * In partial result we get quick updates about current hypothesis. In
     * keyword spotting mode we can react here, in other modes we need to wait
     * for final result in onResult.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
        if (hypothesis == null)
            return;

        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        if (text.equals(KEYPHRASE))
            switchSearch(MENU_SEARCH);
        else if (text.equals(DIGITS_SEARCH))
            switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
        else if (text.equals(PHONE_SEARCH))
            switchSearch(PHONE_SEARCH);
        else if (text.equals(FORECAST_SEARCH))
            switchSearch(FORECAST_SEARCH);
        else
            Log.e(TAG, "onPartialResult: " + text);
    }

    /**
     * This callback is called when we stop the recognizer.
     */
    @Override
    public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
        if (hypothesis != null) {
            String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
            Log.e(TAG, "onResult: " + text);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    }

    /**
     * We stop recognizer here to get a final result
     */
    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        if (!recognizer.getSearchName().equals(KWS_SEARCH))
            switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
    }

    private void switchSearch(String searchName) {
        recognizer.stop();

        // If we are not spotting, start listening with timeout (10000 ms or 10 seconds).
        if (searchName.equals(KWS_SEARCH))
            recognizer.startListening(searchName);
        else
            recognizer.startListening(searchName, 10000);

        String caption = getResources().getString(captions.get(searchName));
        Log.e(TAG, "switchSearch: "+ caption);
    }

    private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {
        // The recognizer can be configured to perform multiple searches
        // of different kind and switch between them

        recognizer = SpeechRecognizerSetup.defaultSetup()
                .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
                .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))

                .setRawLogDir(assetsDir) // To disable logging of raw audio comment out this call (takes a lot of space on the device)

                .getRecognizer();
        recognizer.addListener(this);

        /* In your application you might not need to add all those searches.
          They are added here for demonstration. You can leave just one.
         */

        // Create keyword-activation search.
        recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);

        // Create grammar-based search for selection between demos
        File menuGrammar = new File(assetsDir, "menu.gram");
        recognizer.addGrammarSearch(MENU_SEARCH, menuGrammar);

        // Create grammar-based search for digit recognition
        File digitsGrammar = new File(assetsDir, "digits.gram");
        recognizer.addGrammarSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH, digitsGrammar);

        // Create language model search
        File languageModel = new File(assetsDir, "weather.dmp");
        recognizer.addNgramSearch(FORECAST_SEARCH, languageModel);

        // Phonetic search
        File phoneticModel = new File(assetsDir, "en-phone.dmp");
        recognizer.addAllphoneSearch(PHONE_SEARCH, phoneticModel);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + error.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeout() {
        switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
    }
}
```

My code is almost the same as [pocketsphinx-android-demo](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo/blob/8f5ccb88eb24eb5155f52a7366911e5c615e254e/app/src/main/java/edu/cmu/pocketsphinx/demo/PocketSphinxActivity.java). The only differences are that I am doing this in a service class, instead of an Activity and I am not asking the user for microphone permission since I do that in the MainActity already. Well, my code has some warnings but no errors.

When I run my app, I get this message (see the full [stack trace](https://gist.github.com/RezaS/e85fcc559ce329cb9b3cd1f629239fc5)):

> E/SstService: switchSearch: To start demonstration say "oh mighty
> computer".

But when I say "oh mighty computer" (or anything else), nothing happens. I don't even get an error. So I have no idea where I am stuck and what I am doing wrong.

If there is someone familiar with that library, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Possibly related: [Access microphone in android 9 while the app is in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63130222/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks for this info, you are right! I have allowed the permission manually but now I get some weird logs (the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47961483/what-is-the-meaning-of-these-logs-which-are-the-results-of-kws-test-py-in-pocket). I am using the virtual device Pixel 2 API 30 with Android 11.0. How can I find out that my microphone is the problem?